# Why is IPv6 port not available

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am not a computer scientist but am trying to run a code on chromedriver so I can source some webdata for academia. Please help! :)

I have chrome 76 - and placed a new path with the chromedriver 76 in the folder. however when I run -chromedriver in CMD it returns an error.

The error says (in french as french language PC) that only one use is normlaly authorised for each port.  IPv6 port not available.

Basically  , test-ipv6.com says i don't have connectivity there, and lists the following steps:

```
Your IPv4 address on the public Internet appears to be 81.152.206.137

Your Internet Service Provider (ISP) appears to be BT-UK-AS BTnet UK Regional network

No IPv6 address detected [more info]

You appear to be able to browse the IPv4 Internet only. You will not be able to reach IPv6-only sites.

To ensure the best Internet performance and connectivity, ask your ISP about native IPv6. [more info]

We are sometimes unable to detect Teredo and 6to4 when using HTTPS. [more info]

HTTPS support on this web site is in beta. [more info]

Your DNS server (possibly run by your ISP) appears to have no access to the IPv6 Internet, or is not configured to use it. This may in the future restrict your ability to reach IPv6-only sites. [more info]
```

The CMD return for ''-chromedriver'' is the following:

Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1566119056.759][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error: Une seule utilisation de chaque adresse de socket (protocole/adresse rÚseau/port) est habituellement autorisÚe. (0x2740)
IPv6 port not available. Exiting...

Comment: My internet provider wants me to switch to a ''business account'' (IE I need to have a registered business number) for me to have IPv6 enabled.... 
Is there a workaround?